# jQuery have variable containing mulitple variables

Tags: jquery

I have a list of variables, which are getting out of hand

I was wondering if i can put all these varialbes within another variable,
or function of some sort
for easy management

```
var contentsId = $(cur).find("contentsId").text()
var status = $(cur).find("status").text()
var title = $(cur).find("title").text()
var description = $(cur).find("description").text()
var thumbnailUrl = $(cur).find("thumbnailUrl").text()
var coverUrl = $(cur).find("coverUrl").text()
```

Comment: you can always add them to an array $data = []; $data['contentId'] = .... etc.

Comment: `function getText(sel){ return $(cur).find(sel).text() }` ?

Comment: ah i got the question now! thnx ogeez - i thought he meant one place for his variables!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard JavaScript data structures are [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) (for groups of unordered data with named keys) and [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) (for ordered data).

```
var myThing = {
   foo: "some value",
   bar: "some other value"
};
myThing.baz = "yet another value";

alert(myThing.foo);
alert(myThing["bar"]);
var key = "baz";
alert(myThing[key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var vars = ['contentsId', 'status', 'title'];

$.each(vars, function(key, value){
    var cur = $('#testDiv');
    vars[value] = $('#testDiv').find('.' + value).text();
});
```

To get all values and assuming efficiency isn't too important - the above would let you create all items under 'vars' - then simply call an item by doing -

```
vars['contentId'];
```

If items are likely to change between calling the `$.each` and the time you access them then you will need to re-evaluate them.

obviously I have manually entered a few bits as I can't see the HTML that matches it.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpG6Q/)